# What technique can be used to solve this 6x6 sudoku?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image: 6x6 Sudoku]

Which Sudoku technique can be used to solve this? The screenshot is from the open source Sudoku app by SECUSO (Security Usability Society) for the Android platform.

Comment: @Rajesh: Sorry for the nitpicking :x Could you please edit the attribution in the question? (Comments are supposed to be "deletable")

Comment: I'm new to this. Let me know step by step on what I need to do.

Answer (score 18):

You can do sudoku to

> whatever is in row 4, column 5.

That will eventually place the same digit in a spot where a three cannot go:

> [image]

After that deduction, the grid will basically fill itself.

> [image]

The technique that finds relationships like this is called "colouring the pair". When you have a lot of squares around the grid with the same two options only, it's a handy way to give an identity to the two options of the pair. Even if it hadn't conveniently placed a 1-or-3 in a spot that already sees a three, continuing to colour in the "squares that can only be 1 or 3, but cannot be green" in a different colour would have shown that the square in the bottom left corner (r6c1) sees both colours (both numbers of the 1-3 pair) and must therefore be a 2.

Comment: Thank you for the details on "coloring the pair" technique

Comment: Thanks for the technique! For clarity of my understanding, you mean R6C1 sees both the green 1-3 R3C1 and the white 1-3 R6C5, right?

Comment: @justhalf Exactly. Usually one would use two distinct colours like red and green, with white being "undecided", but here I happened to find a shortcut that resolved everything before I coloured in the red 1-3s, so my reds are still white, if that makes any sense :-)

Comment: Yep, that's what prompted my clarification question, haha. No biggies.

Answer (score 1):

Using chess notation (rows 1 to 6 bottom to top and columns a to f, left to right)

```
.---------------------------------.
| 145  6    14   | 135  2    134  | 6
| 1245 3    124  | 15   6    14   | 5
|----------------+----------------|
|*13   5    6    | 2    4   *13   | 4
| 1234 124  1234 | 6   *13   5    | 3
|----------------+----------------|
| 6    14   134  | 13   5    2    | 2
| 2-13 12   5    | 4   *13   6    | 1
'---------------------------------'
  a    b    c      d    e    f
```

Double Kite (1 and 3) [* marked cells] => 1 and 3 are false at a1.

due to the linked cells e1,e3,f4,a4 we have a chain of implications:
if 1 is false at e1, it is true at e3, false at f4 and true at a4,
so either 1 is true at a4 or 1 is true at e1, and (same idea)
either 3 is true at a4 a4 or 3 is true at e1.

Another way:

Remote Pair (13) [* marked cells] => 1 and 3 are false at a1.
We have either a4=1,e1=3 or a4=3,e1=1
because of the sequence 1-3-1-3 or 3-1-3-1 at the marked cells.

With a1=2 the puzzle is easily solved.

Answer (score -2):

If the upper right hand square is a 3, you can follow around the 1,3 squares until you force the bottom left squares to be a 1,2 pair which forces row 5, column 4 to be a 1. This, of course forces a second 3 to be in the upper right box, which is not allowed. The upper right square becomes a 1,4. This immediately answers the entire 1,3 system, the upper right box and the makes the second row, third column a 2 (by uniqueness).

Comment: I'm not following. If R1C6 is 3, then R3C6 is 1, R4C5 is 3, R6C5 is 1. Then R6C2 is 2 and R6C1 is 3. R5C2 and R5C3 are then 1,4 pair. No contradiction there yet, it seems?

Comment: The first step ("If the upper right hand square [1,3, or 4] is a 3") feels a lot like "try something and see if it turns out impossible". This is called bifurcation (which in its extreme form is basically just guessing), and even if you were a person that doesn't mind a method being somewhat distasteful as long as it produces results, the specific thought chain is unnecessarily long in both directions: You could just say: "if r3c6 is a 1, then both the bottom left squares are twos", and be done with it.